# disabling mouseover navigation in fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

i'm using  fullPage.js for a single page website.
when i view the site in IE 11 (also the demo pages @ http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ ) if the mouse goes toward the edge of the page it scrolls very quickly in that direction...

is there a way of disabling the mouseover navigation?

for my site its quite unnecessary as you can already scroll with mouse wheel or with a static menu... on side scrolling slides there are the navigation arrows...

in chrome the examples work much better... scrolling only occurs when clicking on navigation items or on using the mouse wheel..

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of the plugin. Currently the 2.2.5.
Your problem was already solved in previous versions.

Comment: i updated to 2.2.5 from 2.2.0 and still have the problem...
i've tried it on a second computer with identical version of IE and it works ok...
i'm using windows 8.1 and other computer is using windows 7, if that is in any way relevant ...
absolutely fantastic plugin btw, great job :)

Comment: @Dog No its not relevant. Your browser is probably caching the old .js file you were loading. Force a reload with CTRL + F5. It you can not reproduce your problem in another IE 10, then the problem is in your computer, not in the code.